# MySql Query: Getting a record count within query

Tags: mysql

I got my query working but it doesn't count the rows... in my left outer join.

```
 SELECT mUserId,mUserName,COALESCE(x.likeId,0) AS likeCount 
    FROM likes 
    LEFT JOIN members ON likes.likeMember = members.mUserId 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT likeId, count(*) n FROM likes WHERE likeMember = likes.likeMember) x ON likes.likeMember = x.likeId 
    WHERE likeDate > '2014-11-16 07:44:47' 
    GROUP BY likeMember 
    ORDER BY `likeCount` DESC
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your GROUP BY clause occupies a different scope to your aggregate function. Now, if we had CREATE and INSERT statements, and a corresponding desired result...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT mUserId,mUserName,COALESCE(x.likeId,0) AS likeCount 
FROM likes LEFT JOIN
     members
     ON likes.likeMember = members.mUserId LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT likeId, count(*) n
      FROM likes
      WHERE likeMember = likes.likeMember
     ) x
     ON likes.likeMember = x.likeId 
WHERE likeDate > '2014-11-16 07:44:47' 
GROUP BY likeMember 
ORDER BY `likeCount` DESC;
```

It is a bit absurd.  Either do an aggregation in the subquery.  Or do an aggregation in the outer query.  But not both.  I suspect you want something more like this:

```
SELECT m.mUserId, m.mUserName, COUNT(*) AS likeCount 
FROM likes l LEFT JOIN
     members m
     ON l.likeMember = m.likeId 
WHERE l.likeDate > '2014-11-16 07:44:47' 
GROUP BY l.likeMember 
ORDER BY `likeCount` DESC;
```

The problem with your subquery is the `WHERE` clause.  You think it is correlated to the outer query.  But it is really interpreted as:

```
      WHERE likes.likeMember = likes.likeMember
```

In other words, the condition is true whenever `likes.likeMember` is not `NULL`.